# Shorthand for current memory address in gdb?

Tags: c, gdb

Is there some short-hand form to get the value of the current memory address in `gdb`? For example:

```
─── Assembly ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
0x0000000000401000  04 03     ? add    $0x3,%al
```

And instead of doing:

```
>>> x/2bt 0x0000000000401000
0x401000 <_start>:  00000100    00000011
```

I could just do something like:

```
>>> x/2bt . # or whatever short-form it is
0x401000 <_start>:  00000100    00000011
```

Is there something for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$pc` as a shortform of the program-counter, so:

```
>>> x/2bt $pc
0x401000 <_start>:  00000100    00000011
```